# Understanding Quotient spaces - Shrinking down

Tags: functional-analysis, quotient-spaces

I am looking at Page 57 of Kreyszig's Functional Analysis, and I have been given an exercise:

Let $X=\Bbb R^3$ and $Y=\{(\xi_1,0,0)| \xi_1 \in \Bbb R\}$

1) Find $X/Y$:

So $X/Y=\{[x]:x+Y,\forall x\in X\}$. Now if $Y=\{(1,0,0)\}$ I would think of $X/Y$ as compressing $\Bbb R^3$ into the space $\{(x,y,z):x,y,z\in\Bbb R, 0\leq x\leq 1\}$. That may be wrong already, is it? But when $\xi_1\in \Bbb R$, it looks like we are setting $x=0$ in the quotient space always, is that correct?

2) Find $X/X$: I imagine this gives us only $\{(0,0,0\}$

3) Find $X/\{0\}$: This gives us back $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: $2$ and $3$ are roughly correct ( you get a point and $\mathbb{R}^3$).  And your thought that $X/Y$ is like setting $x_1$ to $0$ is pretty accurate.  But your example about $Y={(1,0,0)}$ is off.

Comment: @Callus I was thinking of $Y=(1,0,0)$ as setting a modulo $1$ condition to the first coordinate, if that helps see where my incorrect thoughts originated, thanks!

Comment: Got it.  that's not a bad thought, but it's not what is meant by quotient here. Note that there have to be some conditions on $Y$ for the definition you gave to yield another vector space ( eg. $Y$ should be a sub-vector space )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\mathbb R^3/\{(x_1,0,0); x_1\in\mathbb R\} \cong \mathbb R^2$. (As vector spaces and also as normed linear spaces - it is a bit unclear what you are asking about, but the answer is the same; I will deal with vector spaces.)

Here are two possible ways how to look at this:

- You can notice that $[(0,x_2,x_3)]$ for $x_2,x_3\in\mathbb R$ are all equivalence classes (and none of them is listed twice here). So $[(0,x_2,x_3)]\mapsto(x_2,x_3)$ is the isomorphism between these two spaces.
- For vector spaces you can apply [the first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem) to the surjective linear map $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^2$ given by $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto(0,x_2,x_3)$.

Answer (score 1):

1. If $Y=\{(1,0,0)\}$, then $Y$ is **not** a vector space, this $X/Y$ is not defined.
2. You are **almost** correct. In fact, $X/X$ is a set of **equivalence classes**. Therefore, any element of $X/X$ will be $[x]$ for some $x\in X$. In the case of $X/X$, the space is equal to $X/X = \{[(0,0,0)]\}$ (note the square brackets you don't have, so the only element of $X/X$ is not $(0,0,0)$, which is an element of $X$, but $[(0,0,0)]$). You are correct, however, that $X/X$ is **isomorphic** to $\{(0,0,0)\}$
3. Again, as in $2$, you are almost correct. $X/\{0\}$ is not $\mathbb R^3$, but it is **isomorphic** to $\mathbb R^3.$